# Conversor de moneda HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buen día a todos, necesito ayuda con un convertidor de moneda sencillo, que pueda convertir de dolar a euros y viceversa, algo por el estilo https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_length_converter_feet_to_meters
[image: Conversor]

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: algo similar a https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_length_converter_feet_to_meters

Comment: Y porque no lo haces igual?

Comment: si estas teniendo dificultades con alguna parte en concreto lo primero que debes hacer es incluir tu codigo en la pregunta

Comment: Coloca el código que llevas hasta el momento, para que en base a eso se te vaya ayudando.

Answer (score 2):

Lo único que he hecho ha sido copiar el código del ejemplo que indicas y hacerle un par de cambios para que sea un conversor de moneda, tendrías que darle los estilos necesarios para que quede como lo tienes en la imagen:

```js
function eurosDolares(valNum) {
  document.getElementById("inputDolares").value=valNum*1.156236;
}
function dolaresEuros(valNum) {
  document.getElementById("inputEuros").value=valNum*0.864875337;
}
```

```html
<html>
<title>Conversor de moneda.</title>
<body>
<h2>Conversor de moneda.</h2>
  <p>
  <label>Euros</label>
  <input id="inputEuros" type="number" placeholder="Euros" oninput="eurosDolares(this.value)" onchange="eurosDolares(this.value)">
</p>
<p>
  <label>Dolares</label>
  <input id="inputDolares" type="number" placeholder="Dolares" oninput="dolaresEuros(this.value)" onchange="dolaresEuros(this.value)">
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: la idea del sitio es apoyar en dudas especificas de código, por lo que notas el usuario no muestra avance alguno; por lo cual la pregunta no se apega a la normatividad del sitio, aunque se agradece tu ayuda te recomiendo leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo en que la pregunta no es muy adecuada al sitio y dudé en responderla, pero no me llevó nada de tiempo, por lo que si es eliminada no pierdo nada, y si no y la respuesta le sirve, habré ayudado a alguien, aunque no sea de la mejor forma posible. Tendré tu consejo en cuenta para futuras ocasiones.

Comment: yo se que no lleva mucho tiempo, se agradece tu ayuda en serio pero la idea es que los OP es decir los que postean sus preguntas muestren sus intentos, avances y dudas si no al llevarse así el código no aseguras que realmente lo comprende te recomiendo leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer